# Stuck in a conditional redirect loop

Tags: javascript, oracle-apex

I want the application to change the url in the browser to set the parameters if the parameters do not match the item value on initial load of the page.

I tried to create a conditional check to see if the substring matched anywhere within the URL. However, I get caught in a loop. Something tells me my use of wildcards is incorrect.

```
  htp.p('<script>
  if(window.location.href !== "*'||:P4_TEAM||'*") {
  window.location.href = "https://apextserverurl/ords/f?p=80001:4:::::P4_TEAM:'||:P4_TEAM||'"
  }
  </script>');
```

Since the page item cannot be null, the thought is on the initial load, it will push the parameters into the URL and adjust accordingly. The actual result shows the url parameters load into the browser correctly, but it seems to fail the logic test on the javascript and keeps refreshing instead

Comment: Would a more declarative approach work? Using conditional branches?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your page refreshes endlessly, because your `if` condition will always be true (Because you can't use wildcards in JavaScript...at least not like that) and `window.location.href` will reload your page.

You could use a Regex, but for your example a simple `string.includes()` is sufficient.

You can just check with `includes()` like so:

```
// If ':P4_TEAM' is not in the url
if(!window.location.href.includes(':P4_TEAM')) {
  // Set the url to the provided string (and refresh the page)
  window.location.href = "https://apextserverurl/ords/f?p=80001:4:::::P4_TEAM:'||:P4_TEAM||'";
}
```